# Synchronized UI => Application.Selection.Start is broken

Tags: c#, vsto

Synchronized context of UI using `System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher`, I try to get cursor position using `Application.Selection.Start` property of Word Add In and it returns false value.

1) `Dispatcher _dispatcher = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;`

2) `_dispatcher.Invoke(TextChanged);`

3)

```
private async void TextChanged()
        {
             var currentSelectionStart1 = Application.Selection.Start;
             await Task.Delay(10);
             var currentSelectionStart2 = Application.Selection.Start;
        }

currentSelectionStart1 and currentSelectionStart2 are wrong
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue solved. For some reason word add-in works differently, and when it is asked about cursor position in the same thread it returns wrong value. But as soon as you launched calculate method it works fine.

```
var selectionRange = Application.Selection.Range;
selectionRange.Calculate();
var currentSelectionStart = selectionRange.Start;
```